# Pandas: Replace index values(int) in column with column values (string) of another dataframe matching the index values

Tags: python, pandas

df1

```
                    STATION NAME     LAT     LON   LAT_rad   LON_rad
                       BEAUFORT  32.400 -80.633  0.565487 -1.407311
    CONWAY HORRY COUNTY AIRPORT  33.828 -79.122  0.590410 -1.380939
               HUSTON/EXECUTIVE  29.800 -95.900  0.520108 -1.673771
              ELIZABETHTON MUNI  36.371 -82.173  0.634794 -1.434189
           JACK BARSTOW AIRPORT  43.663 -84.261  0.762063 -1.470632
  MARLBORO CO JETPORT H E AVENT  34.622 -79.734  0.604268 -1.391621
            SUMMERVILLE AIRPORT  33.063 -80.279  0.577058 -1.401133
```

df2

```
                       STATION NAME     LAT  ...  distance_nearest  id_nearest
  BOOMVANG HELIPORT / OIL PLATFORM  27.350  ...          0.046963           2
                LEE COUNTY AIRPORT  36.654  ...          0.015469           3
                         ELLINGTON  35.507  ...          0.067148           3
      LAWRENCEVILLE BRUNSWICK MUNI  36.773  ...          0.046532           5
                         PUTNAM CO  39.630  ...          0.077857           4
```

I want to replace `"id_nearest"` column which holds indices to `df1` column `"STATION NAME"` with the actual string.
This is what I tried

```
for index, row in df2.itertuples():
    (_id) = (row.id_nearest)

    df2["id_name"] = df1.loc[_id, 'STATION NAME']
```

and this was the output

```
                       STATION NAME     LAT  ...  id_nearest               id_name
  BOOMVANG HELIPORT / OIL PLATFORM  27.350  ...           2  JACK BARSTOW AIRPORT
                LEE COUNTY AIRPORT  36.654  ...           3  JACK BARSTOW AIRPORT
                         ELLINGTON  35.507  ...           3  JACK BARSTOW AIRPORT
      LAWRENCEVILLE BRUNSWICK MUNI  36.773  ...           5  JACK BARSTOW AIRPORT
                         PUTNAM CO  39.630  ...           4  JACK BARSTOW AIRPORT
```

As you can see this is clearly wrong. The `Expected output` is

```
                           STATION NAME     LAT  ...  id_nearest       id_name
  BOOMVANG HELIPORT / OIL PLATFORM  27.350  ...           2   HUSTON/EXECUTIVE
                LEE COUNTY AIRPORT  36.654  ...           3   ELIZABETHTON MUNI
                         ELLINGTON  35.507  ...           3   ELIZABETHTON MUNI
      LAWRENCEVILLE BRUNSWICK MUNI  36.773  ...           5   MARLBORO CO JETPORT H E AVENT
                         PUTNAM CO  39.630  ...           4   JACK BARSTOW AIRPORT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.map()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) to map `id_nearest` to the index of `df1` and get the `df1` column `STATION NAME` values, as follows:

```
df2['id_name'] = df2['id_nearest'].map(df1['STATION NAME'])
```

**Data Input**

```
df1

                    STATION NAME     LAT     LON   LAT_rad   LON_rad
0                       BEAUFORT  32.400 -80.633  0.565487 -1.407311
1    CONWAY HORRY COUNTY AIRPORT  33.828 -79.122  0.590410 -1.380939
2               HUSTON/EXECUTIVE  29.800 -95.900  0.520108 -1.673771
3              ELIZABETHTON MUNI  36.371 -82.173  0.634794 -1.434189
4           JACK BARSTOW AIRPORT  43.663 -84.261  0.762063 -1.470632
5  MARLBORO CO JETPORT H E AVENT  34.622 -79.734  0.604268 -1.391621
6            SUMMERVILLE AIRPORT  33.063 -80.279  0.577058 -1.401133


df2

                       STATION NAME     LAT  distance_nearest  id_nearest
0  BOOMVANG HELIPORT / OIL PLATFORM  27.350          0.046963           2
1                LEE COUNTY AIRPORT  36.654          0.015469           3
2                         ELLINGTON  35.507          0.067148           3
3      LAWRENCEVILLE BRUNSWICK MUNI  36.773          0.046532           5
4                         PUTNAM CO  39.630          0.077857           4
```

**Output:**

```
                       STATION NAME     LAT  distance_nearest  id_nearest                        id_name
0  BOOMVANG HELIPORT / OIL PLATFORM  27.350          0.046963           2               HUSTON/EXECUTIVE
1                LEE COUNTY AIRPORT  36.654          0.015469           3              ELIZABETHTON MUNI
2                         ELLINGTON  35.507          0.067148           3              ELIZABETHTON MUNI
3      LAWRENCEVILLE BRUNSWICK MUNI  36.773          0.046532           5  MARLBORO CO JETPORT H E AVENT
4                         PUTNAM CO  39.630          0.077857           4           JACK BARSTOW AIRPORT
```